# Which approach is better for assigning conditionally?

Tags: javascript

Below code is just initializing two variables, depending on cloudType passed, which can be assigned by either of approaches. In JavaScript less number of lines of code is recommended so I like the second approach also it removes duplication.

Approach one gives me flexibility to add operations in specific case if required in future where as 2nd approach is saving me good amount of bytes also helping me reduce duplication.

```
switch (cloudType) {
    case "aws":
        value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues.aws
        resetText = this._messages.current.aws
        break;
    case "private":
        value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues.private;
        resetText = this._messages.current.private
        break;
    case "azure":
        value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues.azure;
        resetText = this._messages.current.azure
        break;
}
```

Or

```
value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType];
resetText = this._messages.current[cloudType]
```

Comment: The second approach already is more readable IMO - if you want to make things clearer, simply put a comment above, like: `// cloudType may be 'aws', 'private', or 'azure'`

Comment: "*In javascript less number of lines of code is recommended…*" by who? "Less code" is never a good reason, of itself, to adopt a particular pattern. However, the second method is preferable as message values can be independently maintained. The overall code, including the object holding the data, may well be more code.

Comment: The first approach repeats the same bit of code several times, increasing the chance of error.  The DRY principle favors the second approach.

Comment: In many ways this question is off–topic as answers are very much opinion based, and not really about a specific programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site. Although I know, questions in that site will not get attention as much as here on SO. I wish there could be easier methods for moving question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By all means, I prefer the second code.

If your `cloudType` variable has a one-to-one mapping to properties of those two other objects, why not make it clear? This also avoids duplicate code.

To be safe, add these checks to your code:

```
value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType];
resetText = this._messages.current[cloudType]
if (typeof value == "undefined" || typeof resetText == "undefined") {
    // throw some error
}
```

This way you'll know that when a new `cloudType` is added to your system, you should add relevant properties to those other objects.

Comment: `value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType] || "Invalid cloudtype"`

Comment: @mplungjan I don't agree. An invalid value will go around in the program, and who knows when it causes problems? In my opinion, it is vital to [fail fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf).

Comment: Sure: `if (value == "Invalid cloudtype"` :)

Answer (score 1):

Amplifying @Mohammad's answer

The second code is already industry standard of referring to object properties through its keys via brackets `foo['bar']`. If you want to add extra operations, just put in the switch case block below. Still saving you a few  bytes than the first solution you wrote

```
value = this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType];
resetText = this._messages.current[cloudType];

switch (cloudType) {
    case "aws": break;
    case "private": break;
    case "azure": break;
}
```

Considering the keys truly matches directly to the `cloudType` variable, and even if it isn't, I advise matching it.